# How do resize images easily in the browser/before they get to the database?

Tags: reactjs, image, resize

I'm trying to do what I thought would be a super simple thing. I have users uploading images to my site, they can upload any images. I'm using a react carousel to render them. I noticed whilst testing that obviously images different sizes and this makes the carousel a bit weird when rendering them as it can jump between rectangles and squares. so I figured the best way would be resize all the images to the correct size. however, I'm having issues with this.

I've seen lots of answers online like so: [resize image before upload using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542887/resize-image-before-upload-using-javascript)

but I don't want to copy 50~ lines of code and just use if I don't know what it's doing. I searched for packages and found this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp which looks perfect but I got some errors with this I couldn't figure out.

all I want when uploading them is to simply check if width != height and then resize to say 300x300. I am using firebase and I am using their resize image tool. again it's really good but you specify dimensions but I think it treats them as maximum rather than actual. obviously I don't want to lose image quality too and stretch the image. so I'm wondering the best way to achieve this.

Comment: The answer in the question you link to links to https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/how-to-develop-a-html5-image-uploader/ where it explains how to resize an image before uploading it, have you seen it?

Comment: What are the errors you get with jimp?